# How to perform element-wise sum of multiple series, preserving NaNs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame, e.g.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1.0, np.nan, 3.0], 
                   [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], 
                   [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   [np.nan, 8.0, 9.0],
                   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], 
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df =
     a    b    c
0  1.0  NaN  3.0
1  4.0  5.0  6.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  8.0  9.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

I want to sum through each row such that `NaN`s are ignored (i.e. treated as 0), except if the whole row is `NaN` (e.g. row 2). Desired answer is:

```
column_sum(df) =

0   4.0 
1  15.0  
2   NaN 
3  17.0 
4   0.0
```

Note that the sum of row 2 is `NaN`, while the sum of row 4 is `0.0`. This distinction must be kept.

I tried:

```
df.sum(axis=1, skipna=True) = 

0     4.0
1    15.0
2     0.0
3    17.0
4     0.0
```

which gives row 2 as `0.0`. Using `.fillna(0)` does the same thing.

I can see of a way to do this column-by-column, masking the `NaN` values as you go, but is there a more efficient way?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter `min_count=1` in [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html), default value (`0`) return `0` instead `NaN`s:

```
print(df.sum(axis=1, min_count=1))
0     4.0
1    15.0
2     NaN
3    17.0
4     0.0
dtype: float64
```